# ServletOutputStream writes extra bytes to response

Tags: jakarta-ee, filter, gzip, response

Here's my JavaEE application filter#doFilter code

```
public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        GZIPServletResponseWrapper gzipResponse = new GZIPServletResponseWrapper(response);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, gzipResponse);
        gzipResponse.close();

}
```

Here's GZIPServletResponseWrapper code

```
public class GZIPServletResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private GZIPOutputStreamWrapper gzipOutputStream;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;

    public GZIPServletResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (this.printWriter != null) {
            this.printWriter.close();
        }
        if (this.gzipOutputStream != null) {
            this.gzipOutputStream.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (this.printWriter != null) {
            this.printWriter.flush();
        }
        if (this.gzipOutputStream != null) {
            this.gzipOutputStream.flush();
        }
        super.flushBuffer();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (printWriter != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(GET_OUTPUT_STREAM_USED);
        }
        if (this.gzipOutputStream == null) {
            this.gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStreamWrapper(getResponse().getOutputStream(),
                    (HttpServletResponse) getResponse());
        }
        return this.gzipOutputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (gzipOutputStream != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(GET_WRITE_USED);
        }
        if (this.printWriter == null) {
            this.gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStreamWrapper(getResponse().getOutputStream(),
                    (HttpServletResponse) getResponse());
            this.printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    this.gzipOutputStream, getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()));
        }
        return this.printWriter;
    }

}
```

Here's GZIPOutputStreamWrapper code

```
public class GZIPOutputStreamWrapper extends ServletOutputStream {
    private static final String CONTENT_ENCODING = "Content-Encoding";
    private static final String TEXT = "text";
    private GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream;
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    public GZIPOutputStreamWrapper(ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        super();
        this.gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(servletOutputStream);
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        this.gzipOutputStream.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        this.gzipOutputStream.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (isTextFile(response)) {
            response.addHeader(CONTENT_ENCODING, GZIP);
            this.gzipOutputStream.write(b, off, len);
        } else {
            response.getOutputStream().write(b, off, len);
        }
    }

    private boolean isTextFile(HttpServletResponse response) {
        String contentType = response.getContentType();
        return contentType != null && contentType.contains(TEXT);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        this.gzipOutputStream.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.gzipOutputStream.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {
    }
}
```

So what's the task.I have to compress text files to gzip in filter and pass it next. But it writes my js files like this

[image]

What can this happen ? It writes files correct with gzipOutputStream but not with response.getOutputStream()